# Сохранить результат команды в переменную

Tags: ubuntu, bash, переменные

Пытаюсь получить результат так.

```
read engine <<< ibus engine
echo $engine
```

но выдает пустую строку. Если просто написать

```
ibus engine
```

то выдает результат команды, но мне нужно сохранить результат в переменную

Подскажите как.

Спасибо

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Команду в скобки: `$(команда)`

```
RESULT=$(ibus engine)
echo $RESULT
```

Comment: @sergiks, спасибо

Comment: У меня создание переменной LINEFIO=$(${LINEDATA[3]}|iconv -f 'windows-1251' -t 'UTF-8') заканчивается сообщением  line 282: $'\317\340\342\353\376\352\345\342\350\367': команда не найдена
хотя просто echo "${LINEDATA[3]}|iconv -f 'windows-1251' -t 'UTF-8'" проходит на ура, в чем дело ?
                                        L

Comment: test=$(curl -I ya.ru)
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0

Comment: @HelloKatty curl выводит в STDERR прогресс загрузки. Это не попадает в переменную. Рабочий пример: `TEST=$(curl https://ya.ru)` Теперь в переменной `$TEST` находится куча HTML: `echo $TEST`

Answer (score 3):

Команду в обратные апострофы:

```
RESULT=`ibus engine`
echo $RESULT
```

Comment: Устаревшая конструкция, но ответ правильный.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ engine="ibus engine"
$ $engine
xkb:ru::rus
```

Comment: @dimka3210, объясните, пожалуйста зачем в начале каждой строки доллар. Где можно почитать про это? У меня так не работает

Comment: это приглашение терминала. http://i.imgur.com/ynvRkxh.png

Comment: Но это вы просто записали команду в переменную, а как мне записать результат команды, то есть xkb:ru::rus. Чтоб при echo "$engine" выдавало "xkb:ru::rus"?

Comment: Не смог написать. Апострофы съедаются. Вот скрин
http://i.imgur.com/okyyNwn.png

Comment: это тоже оно. спсибо

Answer (score -1):

Это то что я искал. Огромное спасибо! По незнаю допустил эту ошибку (только учусь) и не мог понять почему же у меня не работает переменная, почему не сравнивает.
Было

```
dstring= sed -n '1p' < /root/together

if [ "$dstring" = "$fstring" ]; then
echo  "All ok"

else
  echo "Attention! Something has been changed."
  echo "$fstring (1)"
  echo "$dstring (2)"
fi
```

и вот-так вот

```
fstring= "sed -n '1p' < /root/together-first"
dstring= "sed -n '1p' < /root/together"
```

и ещё несколько разных вариантов.
Когда стало по примеру ниже - у меня всё заработало как нужно и я наконец-то приблизился к завершению своего скрипта. Всем успехов!

```
fstring=$(sed -n '1p' < /root/together-first)
dstring=$(sed -n '1p' < /root/together)

if [ "$dstring" = "$fstring" ]; then
echo  "All ok"

else
  echo "Attention! Something has been changed."
  echo "$fstring (1)"
  echo "$dstring (2)"
fi
```

П.С. Много времени убил.....

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).