# Как получить подстроку из переменной BASH и поместить ее в другую переменную?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, bash, shell, sed

В переменной **UDATA** есть некий текст, мне нужно вырезать из нее подстроку между `r='` и `'` поместить в **другую переменную**. Совсем не могу понять как это сделать средствами bash. Прошу помощи.

```
echo $UDATA | sed "/(r=\')(\w+)(\')/p"
```

Этот код выводит все что есть в переменной не вырезая.

Comment: два вопроса в одном. ответ на второй: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/326774/178576

Answer (score 4, accepted):

можно обойтись без запуска дополнительного процесса, т.е. средствами самого процесса [posix-совместимой оболочки](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02):

```
$ s="p='bla' r='bum' q='bom'"
$ s=${s#*r=\'}
$ s=${s%%\'*}
$ echo $s
bum
```

сначала удаляем префикс `*r=\'`, затем удаляем наиболее длинный суффикс `\'*`

---

но, конечно, можно использовать и дополнительный процесс. например, программу *sed*:

```
$ s="p='bla' r='bum' q='bom'"
$ s=$(echo $s | sed "s/.*r='//;s/'.*//")
$ echo $s
bum
```

Comment: Спасибо! Все работает!

Answer (score 1):

Можно так `NEW_VAR=$(echo "<text>" | grep -E -o "<regexp>")`:

- Флаг `-E` для regexp
- Флаг `-o` для возврата только соответствия

Или можно так `NEW_VAR=$(echo "<text>" | sed -E "s#(g1)(g2)(g3)#\2#g")`

Answer (score 1):

***Если у вас одно совпадение в каждой/единственной строке***, можно использовать GNU `sed`:

```
UDATA="text... r='Value' here."
sed -nE "s/.*r='([^']*).*/\1/p" <<< "$UDATA"
# => Value
```

См. [пример](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/P9TFMcTRVqkktaJET09PochWPSwxpzRVXSEjtShVT4mrODVFQTfPVUGpWF9PCyirER2nHqulqaelH2OoX6CkYGNjo6CkAjZF6f9/AA). Подробности:

- `-n`
- `E` - POSIX ERE
- `s/.*r='([^']*).*/\1/p`: найти и заменить, а потом показать результат (`/p`):

  - `.*` - 0 и более символов
  - `r='` - подстрока `r='`
  - `([^']*)` - Подмаска 1: ноль и более символов, отличных от `'`.
  - `.*` - строка
  - `\1`  - заменить целое совпадение значением в первой подмаске

***Если необходимо найти все совпадения, даже если в одной строке их несколько*** и есть возможность использовать GNU `grep`, используйте

```bsh
UDATA="text... r='Value' here."
grep -oP "r='\K[^']*" <<< "$UDATA"
# => Value
```

См. [пример](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/P9TFMcTRVqkktaJET09PochWPSwxpzRVXSEjtShVT4krvSi1QEE3P0BBCSgV4x0dpx6rpaRgY2OjoKQC1qv0/z8A).

- `-o` - выводится не вся строка, а только найденное совпадение
- `P` - используется библиотека PCRE
- `r='` - буквальный текст
- `\K` - удаляет из буфера совпадения весь текст
- `[^']*` - ноль и более символов, отличных от `'`